# Sikuli Random - function that randomly click one of the location

Tags: python, random

Iam looking for function in python that choosing random defined function.

I got 4 function :

```js
w_lewo = Location(345,400)
w_prawo = Location(1570,400)
w_gore = Location(945,900)
w_dol = Location(945,870)
```

And I need function that randomly click one of the location above.

Comment: Newbie question I know but python is new for me and Iam looking for it, for ages

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. Python has a `random` library, why not start there?

Comment: Best if I change that function intro a list or something and chage it intro one function that have already declared randomly choosing. Sorry for my english hope u understend it somehow

Comment: I don't, sorry; perhaps you could find someone who can translate it more clearly for you?

Comment: Though it will be easy for u guys. sending me to lib's does not help me understend how to build the function

Comment: I was thinkingabout something like list = { random function's_above }

Comment: and than just click(list) - but ofcourse that does not work for me :)

Comment: Well stop thinking and *try it*, or you'll never get anywhere!

Comment: Thats a good point, I have very comlicated program already and my try hard always goes to crash my program

Comment: Then you need to split your program down into simple separate parts that you can test independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned yourself, you can store your `Location` objects in a list:

```
objectsList = [w_lewo, w_prawo, w_gore, w_dol]
```

then you can use a `randint` method from a `random` library like it was suggested here to randomly pick a number between 0 and the length of your (4 in our case).

```
randomListElement = objectsList[random.randint(0,len(objectsList)-1)]
```

Then you can do whatever you want with this element, click for example.

Comment: I made it like this and it works!